# Formula to find last value in row and label with Column Top

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Google Spreadsheets. I'll be using this image from a very similar question.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa8Ez.png [a link][Google Spreadsheet Formula to get last value in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982146/google-spreadsheet-formula-to-get-last-value-in-a-row)

Instead of giving the value, I want the Column top to show. So the H column would look something like: 2 1 3 1 4
(The product numbers from Row 1)

If it helps =index(B2:G2;1;counta(B2:G2)) was the answer given to the original question. My values would be words instead of numbers. It'd need to track the last 'Yes' in the row with the column top being dates.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be easy:

=index($B$1:$G$1;1;counta(B2:G2)) - if you write this to the H2 cell, it should search the "N"th element in the FIRST row ($B$1:$G$1) - where N represents the value of non-empty cells in that row (B2:G2).

You can then populate this H2 formula downwards.

Let me know if this helps.